Error while calling an instruction with PDA in client side code
I’m trying to send SOL to a “hold account” (which I’m thinking should be a PDA) and then only be able to claim it from the address that sent this SOL. I am getting an error as I’m trying to now call the “send_sol” instruction client side.
lib.rs
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SendSOL<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,  // The sender of the SOL, the one who will sign the transaction

    #[account(
        init,  // Initialize the hold account (PDA) on this transaction
        payer = owner,  // The owner will pay for the account creation and rent
        seeds = [b"hold_account", owner.key().as_ref()],  // PDA derivation using a seed
        bump,  // Bump seed for the PDA
        space = 8 + HoldAccount::INIT_SPACE  // Space for storing account (8 bytes for SOL storage)
    )]
    pub hold_account: Account<'info, HoldAccount>,  // This is where SOL will be held (PDA for temp hold)

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_account: SystemAccount<'info>,  // The account sending SOL

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,  // The system program handles SOL transfers
}

Here is my .tsx file where I’m trying to be able to successfully call the send_sol instruction:
const sendSOL = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['pogo', 'send_sol', { cluster }],
    mutationFn: async ({ keypair, amount, message }: { keypair: Keypair, amount: number, message: string }) => {

      // Interact with the Anchor program to invoke send_sol
      return await program.methods
        .sendSol(new anchor.BN(amount * 10 ** 9), message)  // Send SOL in lamports (1 SOL = 10^9 lamports)
        .accounts({
          owner: keypair.publicKey!,
          hold_account: await PublicKey.createWithSeed(keypair.publicKey!, "hold_account", programId),  // The derived PDA
          from_account: keypair.publicKey!,
          system_program: SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc()
    },
    onSuccess: (signature) => {
      transactionToast(signature)
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error('Transaction Error:', error)
    }
  })

I get this error on “hold_account”:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'holdAccount' does not exist in type 'ResolvedAccounts<{ name: "owner"; writable: true; signer: true; } | { name: "holdAccount"; writable: true; pda: { seeds: [{ kind: "const"; value: [104, 111, 108, 100, 95, 97, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116]; }, { ...; }]; }; } | { ...; } | { ...; }>'.

For additional context, here is the relevant code in my IDL:
{
      "name": "send_sol",
      "discriminator": [
        214,
        24,
        219,
        18,
        3,
        205,
        201,
        179
      ],
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "owner",
          "writable": true,
          "signer": true
        },
        {
          "name": "hold_account",
          "writable": true,
          "pda": {
            "seeds": [
              {
                "kind": "const",
                "value": [
                  104,
                  111,
                  108,
                  100,
                  95,
                  97,
                  99,
                  99,
                  111,
                  117,
                  110,
                  116
                ]
              },
              {
                "kind": "account",
                "path": "owner"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "from_account",
          "writable": true
        },
        {
          "name": "system_program",
          "address": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
        }
      ],
      "args": [
        {
          "name": "amount",
          "type": "u64"
        },
        {
          "name": "message",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    },


This worked out for me, though I don't quite understand why there was an issue!
https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/14800/26650
